# iphone sdk -Loading PDF from document directory

Tags: iphone, ios4, pdf, document

I'm Using [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) project to show my PDFs in my iphone project but i have a problem when i'm trying to display the pdf from the document not from bundle .. i think it's simple but have a trick i can't get cause i'm not guru in pdf reading :)

i'm using the following code

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
pListPath = [ documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.fileName]];


CFURLRef pdfURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pListPath];    


//  CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("fekhElSunaI.pdf"), NULL, NULL);

pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
NSLog(@"%@",pListPath);

//    CFRelease(pdfURL);

   [self init];
}
```

you'll notice that i've put the code in the viewWillAppear not in the init as leaves do ..
the pdf is not appear and not initialized 
i've used the solution that is on this [LINK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61450-load-pdf-documents-directory.html#post369478) and it didn't work either

so any one here have something to help me with :)

Comment: What's the problem or the question?   You said you have a problem.  Does it not display?  Do you get an error?

Comment: yeah it doesn't display at all although it get the number of pages that why i'm doubting there's a problem in the position of the code

Answer (score 0):

You've put the code in viewWillAppear, and that's probably your issue.  Elsewhere the code might assume the code is already called, and the PDF already there.  Try putting it in init, and see what happens.  viewWillAppear might get called several times.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
- (id)init {
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.pdf"];
  pdfURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];    
  NSLog(@"myString %@",myPathDocs);

  pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);        //        }

  size_t pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
}
```

for your Leavies View `init` function